# How to add an animation to a button when its command has executed in winui 3?

Tags: uwp, custom-controls, winui-3, visualstates

In a WinUi 3 application I created a custom `Command` that implements both an `Executed` event and a `HasExecuted` property with change notification.
I want to design a `CustomControl`, preferably inheriting from `Button` that will show an animation once the `Executed` event is fired or the `HasExecuted` property becomes `true`.

Up to now I have come up with this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace BridgeSystems.Framework.WinUI.Controls;

public class ConfirmButton : Button
{

protected Thickness _cachedMargin;
protected Brush _cachedForeground;
protected Brush _cachedBackground;
protected double _cachedFontSize;

public ConfirmButton()
{
    DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ConfirmButton);
}

protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    _cachedMargin = Margin;
    _cachedForeground = Foreground;
    _cachedFontSize = FontSize;
    _cachedBackground = Background;
}

public bool HasBeenExecuted
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(HasBeenExecutedProperty);
    set => SetValue(HasBeenExecutedProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty HasBeenExecutedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(HasBeenExecuted), typeof(bool), typeof(ConfirmButton), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnExecuted));

private static void OnExecuted(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = d as ConfirmButton;
    if (button == null) return;

    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
    {
        button.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        button.FontSize = 20;
    }
    else
    {
        button.Foreground = button._cachedForeground;
        button.Background = button._cachedBackground;
        button.FontSize = button._cachedFontSize;
    }
}
```

}

This works, but the green background is there to stay. I need to implement an animation to make the green background temporary.
Delving deeper into this I found that the implementation above is not the way to go. It should be done by implementing a custom Visual state in the `generic.xaml`file. and using `GotoVisualStyle`in the `OnExecuted` method. But once I start using a style in `generic.xaml the button loses its default behaviour. Is there a way to do this without designing the Button from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Storyboarded animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/motion/storyboarded-animations).  You can create your animation in code or in Xaml, and the preferred approach is to start it in code, in `OnExecuted`.

Comment: The provided link is about WPF and Silverlight. OP is asking about WinUI 3

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky way but you can add a VisualState like this:

**generic.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:local="using:VisualStatesExample">
    <Style TargetType="local:ConfirmButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundSizing" Value="InnerBorderEdge" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPadding}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{ThemeResource ControlCornerRadius}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        xmlns:local="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
                        x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        local:AnimatedIcon.State="Normal"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                        ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                        CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                        <ContentPresenter.BackgroundTransition>
                            <BrushTransition Duration="0:0:0.083" />
                        </ContentPresenter.BackgroundTransition>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                                KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                                KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                                KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(controls:AnimatedIcon.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                                KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                                KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                                KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(controls:AnimatedIcon.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                                KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                                KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                                KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <!--  DisabledVisual Should be handled by the control, not the animated icon.  -->
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.(controls:AnimatedIcon.State)" Value="Normal" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                             
                                <!--  Confirmed VisualState  -->
                                <VisualState x:Name="Confirmed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Background" Value="Green" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.FontSize" Value="20" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**ConfirmButton.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace VisualStatesExample;

public class ConfirmButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasBeenExecutedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(HasBeenExecuted),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(ConfirmButton),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, OnExecuted));

    public ConfirmButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ConfirmButton);
    }

    public bool HasBeenExecuted
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(HasBeenExecutedProperty);
        set => SetValue(HasBeenExecutedProperty, value);
    }
    private ContentPresenter? ContentPresenter { get; set; }

    private VisualStateGroup? CommonStatesVisualStateGroup { get; set; }

    private List<VisualState>? AllVisualStatesExceptConfirmed { get; set; }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        ContentPresenter = GetTemplateChild(nameof(ContentPresenter)) as ContentPresenter;

        CommonStatesVisualStateGroup = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(ContentPresenter)
            .Where(x => x.Name is "CommonStates")
            .FirstOrDefault();

        AllVisualStatesExceptConfirmed = CommonStatesVisualStateGroup?.States
            .Where(x => x.Name is not "Confirmed")
            .ToList();
    }

    private static void OnExecuted(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as ConfirmButton)?.ApplyConfirmedVisualState();
    }

    private async Task ApplyConfirmedVisualState()
    {
        if (HasBeenExecuted is false ||
            ContentPresenter is null ||
            CommonStatesVisualStateGroup is null ||
            CommonStatesVisualStateGroup.CurrentState.Name is "Confirmed" ||
            AllVisualStatesExceptConfirmed is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Temporarily remove VisualStates except "Confirmed".
        foreach (VisualState state in AllVisualStatesExceptConfirmed)
        {
            CommonStatesVisualStateGroup.States.Remove(state);
        }

        _ = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Confirmed", false);

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000));

        foreach (VisualState state in AllVisualStatesExceptConfirmed)
        {
            CommonStatesVisualStateGroup.States.Add(state);
        }

        _ = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", false);
    }
}
```